# How to remove Python pip list duplicate items

Tags: python

When I run `pip list` I have some duplicate items:

```
vboxapi            1.0
vboxapi            1.0
vboxapi            1.0
```

When I run `pip inspect` I can see vboxapi is listed 3 times:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "metadata_version": "2.1",
    "name": "vboxapi",
    ...
  },
  "metadata_location": "C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\vboxapi-1.0-py3.11.egg\\EGG-INFO"
},
{
  "metadata": {
    "metadata_version": "2.1",
    "name": "vboxapi",
    ...
  },
  "metadata_location": "C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\vboxapi-1.0-py3.11.egg/EGG-INFO/"
},
{
  "metadata": {
    "metadata_version": "2.1",
    "name": "vboxapi",
    ...
  },
  "metadata_location": "C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\vboxapi-1.0-py3.11.egg\\EGG-INFO"
}
```

Is there any way to remove duplicate items?

Comment: Honestly, this is #912 on the list of things you have to worry about.  Playing with this is just as likely to break things as to fix them.  Just let it be.

Comment: Are you looking to get a list without the duplicate items or to actually remove the duplicates from the system (weird that they have the same path)

Comment: @Samathingamajig Yes, pip lists vboxapi 3 times for a same file. That's why I feel a little uneasy about the duplicates.